# TDictionary multiple output?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Is it possible to store multiple items in TDictionary? I want a simple solution for next

My table looks like:

- LOCATION_ID, CITY, ZIP_CODE
- 1          , England, 2000
- 2          , Hungary, 1000
- 3          , Turkey,  300
- 4          , Germany, 5000 etc...

I want to store all the fields from the table and after search items in it.. Is TDictionary is capable for it? I have a Paradox Table, Query is a simple TQuery

I did a small example with 2 field

```
  var
  stSearch: string;
  vPDX: TDictionary<String, TCity>;
  variable: string; 

  stSearch := '4';
  vPDX := TDictionary<String, String>.Create;      qry_TMP.DatabaseName := 'C:\S_DATABASE';
  qry_TMP.SQL.Text := 'select * from SAMPLE_TABLE';
  qry_TMP.Open;

 while not qry_TMP.Eof do
   begin
   vPDX.AddOrSetValue(qry_TMP.FieldByName('LOCATION_ID').AsString,  qry_TMP.FieldByName('Location').AsString);    
qry_TMP.Next;
end;

if vPDX.TryGetValue(stSearch, variable) then
  showmessage(variable);
```

This code Works but I need another field too (ZIP_CODE).

I tried it with Class but I got only the last item from the Table.

```
 TSampleClass = class
 ZIP_CODe: String;
 Location: String;
 end;

  var
  SampleClass, Value: TSampleClass;
  vPDX := TDictionary<String, TSampleClass>.Create;

  begin

  stSearch := '4';
  SampleClass := TSampleClass.Create;
  vPDX := TDictionary<String, TSampleClass>.Create;  
  qry_TMP.DatabaseName := 'C:\S_DATABASE';
  qry_TMP.SQL.Text := 'select * from SAMPLE_TABLE';
  qry_TMP.Open;

while not qry_TMP.Eof do
  begin
  vPDX.AddOrSetValue(qry_TMP.FieldByName('LOCATION_ID').AsString, SampleClass);     
  SampleClass.ZIP_CODE := Qry_TMP.FieldByName('ZIP_CODE').AsString;
  SampleClass.City := Qry_TMP.FieldByName('City').AsString;
  qry_TMP.Next;
  end;

if vPDX.TryGetValue(stSearch, SampleClass) then
  showmessage(SampleClass.ZIP_CODE + SampleClass.City);
```

Anyone can help what will be the problem? I want Germany and the 5000 ZIP_CODE. Iwant to learn how to use TDictionary. Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `tSampleClass.Create` only once.

Move it inside the `WHILE` statement so that a new instance is created for each record.

Comment: Ooooo!:) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You only create one instance of `SampleClass`, which means that every subsequent use just overwrites the values it contains. You need to create a new instance for every addition to the dictionary.

```
while not qry_TMP.Eof do
begin
  SampleClass := TSampleClass.Create;
  SampleClass.ZIP_CODE := qry_TMP.FieldByName('ZIP_CODE).AsString;
  SampleClass.City := qry_TMP.FieldByName('City').AsString;
  vPDX.AddOrSetValue(qry_TMP.FieldByName('LOCATION_ID', SampleClass);
  qry_TMP.Next;
end;
```